# VueJs download picture from spring boot and display in <img>

Tags: spring, image, spring-boot, vue.js, axios

I developed a spring boot backend with Vue Frontend. I would like to upload a picture and store them in gcloud. The upload is ok. But when I want to download it and display it in a  I have some problems. Sometimes the image received is cut. I have only a half part of it, like if all the bytes are not sent. (The picture is well saved in gcloud I can see it entirely when I go in gcloud console).

How I get my picture in my Spring Boot App :

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/api/comp/picture")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> downloadCompanyAvatarImage(@RequestParam Long id) throws IOException {
        Optional<Comp> comp = compService.findById(id);
        if (comp.isPresent()) {
            if (comp.get().getPictureGeneration() == null
                    && comp.get().getPictureName() == null) {
                return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).build();
            } else {
                BlobId blobId = BlobId
                        .of("xx", comp.getPictureName(),comp.getPictureGeneration());
                Blob image = storage.getString(blobId);

                byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(image.getContent());

                return ResponseEntity.ok()
                        .contentLength(image.getSize())
                        .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(image.getContentType()))
                        .body(encodedBytes);
            }
        } else {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("Comp Not found");
        }
```

And How I get it in my VueJs App :

In Store:

```
  getCompPicture(params) {
    return axios.get(`/api/comp/picture?id=${params}`, { headers: auth.authHeader() }).then(response => {
      return response.data;
    });
  },
```

In my Vue Page :

```
 computed: {
    getPictureUrl() {
      return `data:image/png;base64,${this.picture}`;
    },
  },

method: {
    this.getCompPicture(this.id).then(pic => {
        this.picture = pic;
        this.pictureLoaded = true;
      });
},
```

In html :

```
      <img :src="getPictureUrl"  alt="logo" v-if="!edit && picture && pictureLoaded">
```

Have you an idea about what is wrong?

I have an other solution which is to return a Resource in Spring like that :

```
      InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(image.getContent());
      return ResponseEntity.ok()
          .contentLength(image.getSize())
          .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(image.getContentType()))
          .body(new InputStreamResource(is));
```

If i do that, i can see the picture in the preview of the developpement console but, I have no idea how to display it in the  balise because data are like

```
�PNG
IHDR(��/�gsRGB���gAM
�2�M�m4���p3(�v(
```

Comment: Can you post what you are getting in ${this.picture}? is it base64? if not then do not use data:image/png;base64

Comment: I have something like "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQ.. " Image is displayed but truncated

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you change the `produces` to `MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE`

Example:

```
 @GetMapping(path = "/image", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody byte[] getImage() throws IOException {
        InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("image.jpg");
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
    }
```